# Write test for accepting input from command line

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, io, rspec2

I am fairly new to rspec and want to write test in `rspec` for getting input from command line in `Ruby`. How do I go about it? Also, explain the test. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to test the given standard input or command line arguments e.g. `ruby foo.rb --argument1 --argument2`? Can you give an example of what you are trying to test?

Comment: a = gets kind of requests.I implemented this `@life.stub(:gets) { "5" } (next line) @life.input.should == 5` but i don't know wether this is right practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using mocks:

```
STDIN.should_receive(:read).and_return("your string")
```

Also I like the approach which is described [here](https://gist.github.com/631329/d2b1c2728a24cc3cab2d6967bfef17fe89016778). I think that the last one is more suitable for your case.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is to make such kind of objects swappable.
In your case, `gets` is implicitly called on `$stdin`. So you can make an optional
argument called "input" that defaults to `$stdin` and call gets on it.

Here is an simple example of Calculator that takes some input and gives the result back.

```
class Calculator
  def initialize input = $stdin
    @input = input
  end

  def process
    eval @input.gets
  end
end
```

Now you can run `puts Calculator.new.process`, type `1 + 2` and you will see `3`.

You won't need any special tools for testing this because you can easily pass an IO object
and write to it right in your tests. IO.pipe is a good option for this:

```
describe "Calculator" do
  before do
    reader, @writer = IO.pipe
    @calc = Calculator.new(reader)
  end

  it "can sum up two numbers" do
    @writer.puts "1 + 2"
    result = @calc.process
    result.should eq(3)
  end
end
```

You can also use StringIO instead which is not a real IO and does not require a UNIX-like environment.
Although you will need to rewind the stream each time you write.

```
require "stringio"

describe "Calculator" do
  before do
    @input = StringIO.new
    @calc = Calculator.new(@input)
  end

  it "can sum up two numbers" do
    @input.puts "1 + 2"
    @input.rewind
    result = @calc.process
    result.should eq(3)
  end
end
```

The upside of this approach versus stubbing are less brittle tests and a better design.
The tests are less brittle because if you decide to change the implementation and use getc
instead of gets (read characters one by one) for example you won't need to change the tests.
And the design is better because now you can easily give commands from a different source
such as a file `Calculator.new(File.open("calculated_list.txt"))`. Or a fake IO which you
can use in your tests!